# PHP: Prepared statements (newbie), just need to confirm this about SQL injection

Tags: php, prepared-statement

I have long used the mysql_query() to do my stuff but now I am shifting to prepared statements for two reasons:
performance and no sql injection possibility

This is how I am using it:

```
function add_new_user($e_mail1,$username,$pass)
    {
    require_once "db.php";

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO un_users VALUES ('',?, ?,0,0,?,0)");
$stmt->bind_param('sss', $e_mail1, $username,$pass); 

$stmt->execute();    
$stmt->close();
    }
```

I am not sanitizing the three variables `($e_mail1,$username,$pass)` when i pass them to the function or anything else.

Am I doing it the correct way or did I screw up somewhere or need to do something else?
I'm a newbie with this (still going through the docs) so feel free to shower your knowledge :D

Thanks!

Comment: Looks correct, but you still might want to sanitize the input a little...

Comment: Prepared statements will take care of the sanitization for you. Mind you, they don't prevent BAD data from going into the db... just that the data you're using won't 'break' the query so it causes a syntax error or subverts the query's purpose.

Comment: @evolve What do you mean by that?

Comment: @evolve, I used to do a mysql_real_escape_string() on my data before, I thought that was not needed anymore. So how else would I sanitize my input?

Comment: @alex basically what Marc B said, the prepared statement will prevent SQL injection, but that is all.  Who knows how the data is used once it is inserted into the database, clean valid data is always a good thing.

Comment: Can you define "clean valid data" a little more please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are doing it correctly.